# Logging with Winston: Saving logs per client and deleting data per days

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I installed Winston in a Typescript project and set it up like this:

```
import winston from 'winston'; import dotenv from 'dotenv'; dotenv.config();

const levels = {
    error: 0,
    warn: 1,
    info: 2,
    http: 3,
    debug: 4, }

const level = () => {
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
    const isDevelopment = env === 'development'
    return isDevelopment ? 'debug' : 'warn' }

const colors = {
    error: 'red',
    warn: 'yellow',
    info: 'green',
    http: 'magenta',
    debug: 'white', }

winston.addColors(colors)

const format = winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:ms' }),
    winston.format.prettyPrint(), )

const transports = [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({
        filename: 'logs/error.log',
        level: 'error',
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/all.log' }), ]

const Logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: level(),
    levels,
    format,
    transports, })

export default Logger
```

I use it in the project like this e.g.:

```
Logger.http({type: "Request", shopUrl: shopUrl, shopId: shopId, request: req})
```

Winston saves all logs messages from all shops into two files (all.log and error.log). I need Winston to save Logs into Files based on the shopId. But the shopId is inside the logged Object and I don't know how to access it during logging. And the second thing would be that the files should only hold data of the last 30 days. This is required in order to provide a file download to a shop that requests their logs. Any ideas?